# Need to make circos plot from Enrichment data

Tags: gene, circos

I have a list of genes and their associated pathways. The data was generated using Partek. The data looks like this -

| Gene_in_list | Gene_set | Description | Enrichment score | P.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | hsa | Disease C | 69 | 0.005 |
| Gene1 | hsa | Disease A | 45 | 0.05 |
| Gene2 | hsa | Disease B | 23 | 0.007 |
| Gene2 | hsa | Disease Y | 40 | 0.009 |
| Gene2 | hsa | Disease C | 69 | 0.0001 |

I want to 'split open' the Description column (Which I think means going long to wide in tidyverse terminology?), and transform it to the below table -

| Gene_in_list | Disease A | Disease B | Disease C | Disease Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Gene 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

So that I can use the online circos plot to essentially show, which genes are involved in the pathways.

I was also debating if Enrichment score / p.value could be used as the thickness of connections in circos, but I think it might look too thin / uneven.

Any help appreciated, thanks!